# Copy the cell contents from added sheet to existing sheet in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I copy the contents of cell A1 from Sheet2 to Sheet1 with the formula `=Sheet2!A1`.

The issue is that Sheet2 may not be there.
The Excel document will always contain Sheet1.
Sheet2 will at some point be copied from another Excel document.

How can I make it so when Sheet2 is created or copied the contents from cell A1 in Sheet2 will be shown in Sheet1?

Right now, if I delete Sheet2 I get `=#REF!A1`.
If I re-create it, it stays as `=#REF!A1` and the cell contents do not show in Sheet1.

Comment: `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1")`.  Indirect turns text into a reference.  When you delete Sheet2 the formula will show #REF!, but will show a value once Sheet2 is added back in.  That's just a formula - not VBA, so unless you want it in a VBA procedure or function should probably delete the VBA tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INDIRECT` and `IFERROR`:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1"),"")
```

Note that `INDIRECT` is [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation#volatile-and-non-volatile-functions) and should be used sparingly or avoided if possible.

Comment: It worked! So, based on the documentation you provided, performance seem to be the only issue ant that's why we should be cautious when using it, right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's right, too many volatile formulas will bog the workbook down. Generally a non-volatile formula is preferred over a volatile one.

Comment: @ BigBen - Quick question: is there a way to drag down the cell to copy the formula and update the cell automatically? e.g. `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1"),"")`, `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2"),"")`, `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("Sheet2!A3"),"")`.  Control drag doesn't work, it just copies the same cell number.

Comment: You could use a dynamic reference like `Sheet2!A" & ROW(1:1)`.